# Странное поведение запроса в sqlite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть таблица со столбцами date, value. В дате формат 13-09-2020 00:00 итп. Запрос:

```
SELECT date, value from tablename WHERE date >= strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime', '-1 month');
```

почему то выводит данные за сегодняшний день. Есть нюанс что данных ранее 6 сентября в таблице нет. По логике должно вывестись пусто? Почему такое поведение?
P.S. запрос вида

SELECT date, value from tablename WHERE date >= strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime', '-5 hours');

работает хорошо и выводит верные данные.

Comment: А в чём задача-то?  Вывести от «тогда» до «сейчас» или от «сейчас» до «позже»?

Comment: Задача заключается в выводе данных от "тогда" до "сейчас", то есть вывести данные за месяц (точнее за 31 день, а не с начала первого дня месяца). Использование strftime обязательно, так как datetime имеет другой формат, отличающийся от формата базы данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну, если не возражаете, с рекомендаций:

1. **Никогда** не храните в *SQLite* даты
   в чём-либо кроме *Unix*-времени. Иначе потом
   наедитесь… проблем, особенно со сравнением.
2. Если уж вам очень нужно хранить в *SQLite* даты
   как строки, используйте **только** *ISO 8601*
   в *UTC*. По всё тем же причинам.

Так как уже «есть, что есть», вам надо перевести свои данные
в стандартный вид через костыли:

```sql
WITH tablename_with_correct_date(date, value) AS (
  SELECT SUBSTR(date, 7, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 4, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 1, 2) || ' ' || SUBSTR(date, 12, 5)  AS date
       , value
    FROM tablename
)
SELECT *
  FROM tablename_with_correct_date
 WHERE date >= DATETIME('now', '-31 day')
;
```

А вот уже после этого можете использовать
`STRFTIME`, чтобы вывести итоговые данные в нужном вам
формате. Хотя, честно говоря, это должно быть работой приложения,
а не БД.